# Fast read, fast write, multi index database

Tags: database, mongodb, apache-kafka, cassandra, database-indexes

I have a system composed by

- Kafka
- a Kafka consumer (Java) that read from Kafka and insert data into a Database
- a Database that is currently Mongo
- an (final) application that does several read from the Database.

### Kafka

Kafka has hundreds of topics (with a lot of partitions to scale better) representing entities and each message within a topic represents the latest version of a particular entity.

Messages are in a JSON flat format, so no nested fields are present (as if they were coming from a classic SQL database).

Each message has a key able to represent uniquely that particular entity.
For example, the topic `car` has messages representing cars. If I have two messages with the same key I am actually interested only to the latest message of the two since it will have the last version of the information about that car.

For this reason I use compact policy on kafka topics since I am interested only to the last version of each message having the same key.

Topics have million of messages (sometimes billion) and millions of updates arrive every day. The whole system has usually between 1TB and 20TB of data.

### Database (Mongo)

Each topic has a corresponding mongo collection.

Each collection has at least a unique index (in general multi-key) corresponding to the message key.
Moreover, these collections can be queried also using others set of fields (one or two, usually) and others indexes are added for this reason.

Consequently each collection has usually 2 or 3 multikey indexes:

- The unique index corresponding to the kafka key message is use to make writes and also reads
- The other indexes are only used to make reads. They are uniques or super selective, in general up to 2-3 records are fetched doing queries using these indexes.

### Kafka consumer

This is the application that reads messages from kafka and save them into the Database. It uses the index corresponding to the kafka key message to upsert messages into the collection.

The consumer scales depending on the accumulated lag (100-200 replicas and more).

### Final application

This is the application that uses the data and has also a lot of replicas (100-200 and more).
It does tons of read using the indexes previously defined.

This is a graphical representation of the system
[image]

### The problem

Mongodb response times increase too much while concurrent writes and reads are done.
When the system has not so much stress, read/writes are done in 4-7ms.
When the system is under stress, read/writes are done in 100-1000ms and more.

This is a huge problem since lag on Kafka topic increases and this further increases the stress on the system.

The only thing I can change in this architecture is the database.
I used Mongodb since it was the only database available at that moment and the possibility to define multiple multi-key indexes matched my requirements.

I was thinking about Cassandra (or ScyllaDB), but from the documentation I read that indexes should not be very selective as my case required.
Another approach I was thinking was something like a key-value store having multiple key to lookup records or with a single key, but replicating my data for different keys. But I also need to consider costs: a solution like Redis is not feasible with this amount of data.

My **question** is if you have any suggestion about the Database I should give a try considering my requirements:

- Fast Read
- Fast Write
- Multiple indexes (very selective)
- Able to to this work from 1TB up to 20TB of data

Comment: Couchbase would be the most similar to Mongo, rather than Cassandra. Do you have Mongo replicas/shards? Lag is also a consumer issue, not only a database problem, so are you using multiple threads per consumer, or just scaling replicas to partitions?

Comment: Mongo has three replicas (an M60 con mongo Atlas) and I cannot use sharding for not technical reasons.

Regarding Kafka Consumer I am quite confident it works pretty well.
I observed using monitoring tools that the bottleneck is mongo that after a certain pressure starts to be very slow.

I did not though at Couchbase. It seems to be an interesting alternative.

Comment: As far as the consumer is concerned, unless you have some custom logic, Kafka Connect might provide some better backpressure handling

Comment: Ok, regarding the consumer part I was thinking Kafka Connect too. But still the problem here is that a lot of reads on mongo all together increase significantly the response time. Even though indexes are used.